# date.timezone set issue installing symfony

Tags: symfony, installation, timezone

I am trying to install Symfony on an Ubuntu system with:

```
symfony new my_project
```

But it shows the error:

> date.timezone setting must be set
>   Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).

But I already set it:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

I further added the following code to AppKernel.php:

```
public function init()
{
    // get rid of Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
    parent::init();
}
```

Still it is giving the same error. What am I missing?